Spring Boot Rest service: Could not write JSON: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because attribute is null
I am new to spring boot and I am wondering how to allow a response JSON to include null values for database columns that are nullable. This is my controller, service, repository and model:
package com.findersgame.questtracker.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.findersgame.questtracker.model.MapArea;
import com.findersgame.questtracker.service.MapAreaService;

@RestController
public class MapAreaController {

    private MapAreaService mapAreaService;

    public MapAreaController(MapAreaService mapAreaService) {
        super();
        this.mapAreaService = mapAreaService;
    }
    
    @PostMapping("selected_map_areas")
    public List<MapArea> selectedMapAreas(@RequestBody List<Integer> selectedMapAreas) {
        return mapAreaService.selectedMapAreas(selectedMapAreas);
    }
}


package com.findersgame.questtracker.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.findersgame.questtracker.model.MapArea;
import com.findersgame.questtracker.repository.MapAreaRepository;

@Service
public class MapAreaService {
    
    private MapAreaRepository mapAreaRepository;
    
    public MapAreaService(MapAreaRepository mapAreaRepository) {
        super();
        this.mapAreaRepository = mapAreaRepository;
    }
    
    public List<MapArea> selectedMapAreas(List<Integer> selectedIds) {
        return mapAreaRepository.findAllById(selectedIds);
    }
}

package com.findersgame.questtracker.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.findersgame.questtracker.model.MapArea;

public interface MapAreaRepository extends JpaRepository<MapArea, Integer> {

}

package com.findersgame.questtracker.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "map_areas")
public class MapArea {
    
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column
    private Integer mapTabId;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public Integer getMapTabId() {
        return mapTabId;
    }

    public void setMapTabId(Integer mapTabId) {
        this.mapTabId = mapTabId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

My problem is that when I call http://localhost:8080/selected_map_areas with body [14, 15, 16] I get the following error.
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "this.mapTabId" is null]

I guess it makes sense because in the database, the map_tab_id value is null for both id 15 and 16. I'm guessing that I'm missing an annotation in one of the classes/interfaces above but I have not been able to find which one.

In Java, int is value type and Integer is a reference type.
Value types cannot be null (int will default to 0) while references types can be null.
You need to change the mapTabId's type to Integer.

I tried this solution but I still get the same error. After your answer, I updated the code in the original solution to use Integer instead of int.

@BluePrint the answer here is correct and the error should not be the same anymore. Probably you have not deployed and tested correctly the solution offered in this answer.

@BluePrint It looks like your controller is trying to extract primitive int value from Java Integer type and since some of your Integer fields in MapArea instance are null - fails. Usually jackson mapper is used to convert java to json, so probably you could look into its config or provide your own converter like return mapTabId != null ? return mapTabId.getInt() : null;
